# Sync sqlite database from sql server

Tags: android, database, synchronization, android-sqlite

I am working on a android application in which i have SQlite database on my android device and sql server is on cloud.i want to sync both sqlite db as well as db on cloud.i want If I change database data in Android then It will change data on cloud server.when i change data from server then it should change data in android device. sync will run  in 2-3 days when internet is available.i did google and got a alot of link regarding this,but i dont have a clear picture in mind that ho to do this.     1[google](http://www.quickconnectfamily.org/qcdbsync/docs/java/org/quickconnect/sync/SynchronizedDB.ht     ml).2[google](http://kenyantechie.blogspot.in/2012/04/sqlite-android-to-sql-remote-sync-code.html)anyhelp will be highly appriciated if some1 giv me any sample code to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you have to create an account in account and sync section of android and have to make a service that will keep track of time and data and you have to put a flag or a time stamp  when every sync occur and in sync process you may have to check whether the table data in both table is same or not. If any difference is found merge both tables and replace the duplicate entries.